# eBay Trading API returns 'ISBN is missing a value' error

Tags: php, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I am using eBay Trading API to sell products on eBay.

```
$service = new Services\TradingService(array(
        'apiVersion' => $config['tradingApiVersion'],
        'sandbox' => $config['sandbox'],
        'siteId' => Constants\SiteIds::GB
});


$request = new Types\AddFixedPriceItemRequestType();
$item = new Types\ItemType();
------------------------
------------------------
```

But it returns an error "**ISBN is missing a value. Enter a value and try again.**".
How to set this value or EAN with this API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ISBN can be specified in the [Item.ProductListingDetails.ISBN](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/AddFixedPriceItem.html#Request.Item.ProductListingDetails.ISBN) field.

```
$item->ProductListingDetails = new Types\ProductListingDetailsType();
$item->ProductListingDetails->ISBN = '01234567890';
```